# Can you get more than one Enthusiast or Fanatic badge?

Tags: support, badges

I have seen that some badges allow multiple awards.  Is that true for the Enthusiast or Fanatic badge?

I received an Enthusiast badge a while back, then recently I started another streak of activity and I am now at 33 days of consecutive access but I did not get a second Enthusiast badge.  Is this normal?

Is there an article that explains the rules to badges? (I didn't see anything on the [badge discription page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).)

Comment: If it was possible, I would have 18 fanatic badges by now...

Comment: Judging by how I feel, having just received the "Enthusiast" badge, they should be renamed to "Addict" and "Maniac"!

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Or renamed to "Probably using an auto-open script" and "Definitely using an auto-open script".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, those badges can only be earned once.

If you visit a [badge that allows multiple awards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question), you'll see this appendage on the end of the description:

> This badge can be awarded multiple times.

As for a more thorough description of all the badges, check out the [List of All Badges with Full Description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) on Meta Stack Exchange.